# Post request works just fine in curl but returns 500 when using python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, scrapy, http-status-code-500

this is my python code:

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests as req

class TEst(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.bevonordics.se/alla-produkter/pumpar/poolpumpar/pumpar-med-enkel-hastighet/hayward-poolpump-type-super-pump-17725?c=9857'
    ]

    def parse(self,response):
        soup = Soup(response.text, "lxml")
        yield {
            'parts': self.get_spare_parts(soup, url=response.url)
        }

    def get_spare_parts(self,soup,url):
        crsf_token = soup.find('input',{'name':"__csrf_token"}).get('value').strip()
        print(f"{crsf_token} token>>>>>>>>")
        spare_parts = []
        #the first artcle number getsb all spareparts, if available
        article_no = soup.find('div', class_ ="product-variants-accordion--item").get('data-variantnumber')
        res = req.request(
            method="POST",
            url ='https://www.bevonordics.se/spareparts/spareparts/',
            headers = {
                'x-csrf-token': crsf_token,
                'accept': "a*/*",
                'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
                'accept-language': "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
                'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                'origin': 'https://www.bevonordics.se',
                'referer': url
            },
            cookies = {'cookie':"_gcl_au=1.1.2133245834.1625666558; _ga=GA1.2.44217088.1625666563; _hjid=0b9189a7-774b-4054-8b3f-6679b0b1153d; allowCookie=1; _hjDonePolls=680290%2C680275; __csrf_token-6=qSHpqpknXTd1kkoeKY6xLqyyLLPIcU; session-6=24a607a1be1b0acec621d0950311356a1334f24a5463777a4c8fc6b7ef072990; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=1; _hjTLDTest=1; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; _hjIncludedInSessionSample=1; _gid=GA1.2.592682141.1626017440; _gat_UA-646417-39=1; x-ua-device=tablet; nocache=detail-6"},
            json={'variantNumber': article_no}
        )
        print(res)
        spare_parts.append(res.text)
        return spare_parts
```

this is the curl version:

```
curl 'https://www.bevonordics.se/spareparts/spareparts' \
  -H 'x-csrf-token: qSHpqpknXTd1kkoeKY6xLqyyLLPIcU' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'origin: https://www.bevonordics.se' \
  -H 'referer: https://www.bevonordics.se/alla-produkter/pumpar/poolpumpar/pumpar-med-enkel-hastighet/hayward-poolpump-type-super-pump-17725?c=9857' \
  -H 'cookie: _gcl_au=1.1.2133245834.1625666558; _ga=GA1.2.44217088.1625666563; _hjid=0b9189a7-774b-4054-8b3f-6679b0b1153d; allowCookie=1; _hjDonePolls=680290%2C680275; __csrf_token-6=qSHpqpknXTd1kkoeKY6xLqyyLLPIcU; session-6=24a607a1be1b0acec621d0950311356a1334f24a5463777a4c8fc6b7ef072990; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=1; _hjTLDTest=1; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; _hjIncludedInSessionSample=1; _gid=GA1.2.592682141.1626017440; _gat_UA-646417-39=1; x-ua-device=tablet; nocache=detail-6' \
  --data-raw 'variantNumber=2001257' \
  --compressed
```

I've set headers, cookies and all I think might be the problem, but none works.
I dont seems to get why this would work in curl but not in python.
I dont understand what the problem is, I could make use of some help, thanks :)

Comment: you use different `referer`

Comment: you can use url `https://httpbin.org/post` (in curl and python) and it will send all data in your requests and you can compare if they send the same values.

Comment: I'm not sure but `--data-raw` doesn't means `json` but normal `data` (send by `form`) - so you send data in wrong way.

Comment: on page https://curl.trillworks.com/ you can put `curl` command and convert to Python code but for module `requests`, not `scrapy`. But it also shows that it sends `data`, not `json`. If you use program `postman` (or similar) then it also has function to generate code in Python, curl, etc.

Comment: header `'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` also confirms that it has to be normal `data` (send by `form` in HTML), not `json`

Comment: I don't understand why you use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` in `scrapy`. `scrapy` has own methods to get items from HTML and send request. If you use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` then you don't need `scrapy`. And if you use `scrapy` then you don't need `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by setting x-crsf-token in the cookies :) thanks!